# gem5 scons build fails with "TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'"

Tags: scons, gem5

I am trying to install gem5 on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04 and using commit 9fc9c67b4242c03f165951775be5cd0812f2a705. I have used 
http://learning.gem5.org/book/part1/building.html
and
https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/building
as my guide. As near as I can tell, I have installed all the required dependencies using (some dependencies are repeated in these two lines)

```
sudo apt install build-essential git m4 scons zlib1g zlib1g-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libprotoc-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev python-dev python

sudo apt install build-essential git m4 scons zlib1g zlib1g-dev \
    libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libprotoc-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev \
    python-dev python libboost-all-dev
```

Then, when I try to build gem5 using

```
git clone https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5
cd gem5    
scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j8
```

I get the following output after executing the 'scons' line:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Warning: Failed to find git repo directory: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str':
  File "/home/john/gem5/SConstruct", line 355:
    main['GCC'] = CXX_version and CXX_version.find('g++') >= 0
```

I am not sure how to fix this error or even why this error is occurring; I don't even really know what this error is saying. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is likely due to recent migrations to Python 3 due to str/bytes changes. What's your gem5 commit? Please always provide that. I don't reproduce on gem5 2b63ba5700cd2dc6f2aaf34184aceb93e610dbba also in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: OK, Jason replied on the mailing list: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg17776.html So you are on python3? My default python is python2 on 20.04. This happened because when gem5 forks a release they merge things on release only until the actual release day, I'm against this, but it was the decision.

Comment: My apologies for not including the git commit. It is 9fc9c67b4242c03f165951775be5cd0812f2a705. I read the mail archive link that you provided and it suggested using `python2 scons....` but when I run this I get the message "python2: can't open file 'scons': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". Is there some way of fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. That's the result of running a build system implemented in scons expecting only python2.

If you're stuck here's what you can do to be able to compile until the gem project pushes their Python 3 + SCons changes.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
# create a virtualenv which uses python 2.7
virtualenv -p python2.7 venv27
# activate the virtualenv
. venv27/bin/activate
# Install SCons in the python 2.7 virtualenv
pip install scons
# This will now use the scons installed in a python 2.7 virtualenv.
scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j8
```

This worked for me on an Ubuntu 20.04 system.

Comment: Ah thank you. This seems to be working so far. Thank you guys very much.

Comment: Your issue is unrelated to this question. I suggest you ask a new question and/or reach out to the gem5 project.